# Crystal Reports remove duplicate sections

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to remove duplicated sections of a report. currently I am using the previous() function to do this however I am finding that this removes all references to the field passed into this function. I still want to retrieve the first section it comes across.

Thanks

Comment: group by the duplicating criteria, in that way you only get unique values

Answer (score 2):

In `Section expert`, choose the right section (Details I do suppose) click the Formula button close to the `Suppress` field;
Then type (you can drop field name from available fields)

```
{...yourfield}=previous{...yourfield}
```

*(this mean that this section will be suppressed if some field, i.e. "id" is identical to previous one)*

Answer (score 0):

I would be careful doing the previous() I've used this in the past and noticed it sometimes doesn't display any of the repeated data including the original data until I found a way around it.

Instead try using a unique field for the group but also make sure your table relationships(joins) are set up correctly to reflect what data you want to return.

For example (I'm with education) so I deal with learners and qualifications.
If I want to display learner qualifications I would do it as follows:

```
Relationship - Learner ---> L_Quals
```

Create a group, grouped by Learner.learnerID
Create another group, grouped by L_Quals.QualRef
Suppress the details section

Now this will display like this:

```
LearnerID
-Qualref1
-Qualref2
```

If I was to show the qualifications in the details section and had other tables linked up this could get a little messy with repeating qualrefs and such

Hope this resolves